# Regular expression to find first letter in a string

Tags: ruby, regex

Consider this example string:

```
mystr ="1.         moody"
```

I want to capitalize the first letter that occurs in `mystr`. I am trying this regular expression in Ruby but still returns all the letters in `mystr` (moody) instead of the letter m only.

```
puts mystr.scan(/[a-zA-Z]{1}/)
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your attempt returns all the letters is because you are using the `scan` method which does just that, it returns all the characters which match the regex, in your case letters. For your use case you should use `sub` since you only want to `sub`stitute 1 letter.

I use http://rubular.com to practice my Ruby Regexes. Here's what I came up with http://rubular.com/r/fAQEDFVEVn

The regex is: `/\b[a-z]/`

It uses `\b` to find a word boundary, and finally we ask for one letter only with `[a-zA-Z]`

Finally we'll use `sub` to replace it with its upcased version:

```
"1. moody".sub /\b[a-z]/, &:upcase
=> "1. Moody"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: `{1}` is the default, so doesn't do anything.  What is the purpose of `\b\s?`.  It seems to demand that there be one or two spaces between `1.` and `moody`.

Comment: You're right, didn't need the \s or the {1}. Made the edit. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of help, diego, but your edit didn't seem to have effect.

Comment: That's odd.  I see your edits when I click on "edited", but the (refreshed) page still shows `"1. moody".sub /\b\s?[a-zA-Z]{1}/, &:upcase`.

Answer (score 4):

Do as below using [`String#sub`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-sub)

```
(arup~>~)$ pry --simple-prompt
>> s = "1. moody"
=> "1. moody"
>> s.sub(/[a-z]/i,&:upcase)
=> "1. Moody"
>>
```

If you want to modify the source string use `s.sub!(/[a-z]/,&:upcase)`.

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness, although it doesn’t directly answer your question as posed but could be relevant, consider this variation:

```
mystr ="1.         école"
```

The line `mystr.sub(/[a-z]/i,&:upcase)` (as in [Arup Rakshit’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21538426/214790)) will match the *second* letter of the word, producing

```
1.         éCole
```

The line `mystr.sub /\b\s?[a-zA-Z]{1}/, &:upcase` ([diego.greyrobot’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21538596/214790)) won’t match at all and so the line will be unchanged.

There are two problems here. The first is that `[a-zA-Z]` doesn’t match accented characters, so `é` isn’t matched. The fix for this is to use the [`\p{Letter}` character property](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Properties):

```
mystr.sub /\p{Letter}/, &:upcase
```

This will match the character in question, but won’t change it. This is due to the second problem, which is that `upcase` (and `downcase`) [only works on characters in the ASCII range](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-upcase). This is almost as easy to fix, but relies on using an external library such as [`unicode_utils`](http://rubygems.org/gems/unicode_utils):

```
require 'unicode_utils'
mystr.sub(/\p{Letter}/) { |c| UnicodeUtils.upcase(c)}
```

This results in:

```
1.         École
```

which is probably what is wanted in this case.

This may not affect you if you are sure all your data is just ASCII, but is worth knowing for other situations.

Comment: Good point, Matt.  It's so easy for the English-tongued to forget about the rest of the world.